# hide or show related question in different interval of time

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I am trying to make a small POC in which the requirement is ,"I have hidden a  by default. I want to show it after 5 seconds of clicking on a button and then it will hide automatically after 10 second. then after 5 second it will appear and after 10 second it will disappear. and so on to infinite loop in javascript.
Please help for the same

Comment: This is not a "Do it for me" site. Show us the code you've tried. Look around the setTimeout javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function showOrHide(time) {
  let idTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('field').className =
      document.getElementById('field').className === 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide';
    clearTimeout(idTimeout)
  }, time)
}
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    showOrHide(1000);
    showOrHide(3000);
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="field" class="hide">
    To ja
  </div>
</div>
```